# Mobile backend starter can't write custom id to the datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google Mobile Backend Starter. I'am trying to write a custom ID in a CloudEntity object with .setId but when I try to write it to the datastore using CloudBackend.insert method. It only writes the properties but it doesn't include my custom ID.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    mTrackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trackButton);
    mTrackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        sendData();

        }
    });
}
private void sendData(){

    CloudEntity ce = new CloudEntity("Try");
    ce.setId("Custom_ID");
    ce.put("Key1", "Value1");

    CloudCallbackHandler<CloudEntity> cch = new CloudCallbackHandler<CloudEntity>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(CloudEntity results) {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Sent to cloud", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    getCloudBackend().insert(ce,cch);
}
```

[image: datastore]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: +1, I have the exact same issue. I got around it by using a custom parameter "CustomId" and using a query to select entities rather than .get(). This is just a quick fix and not a real solution to your question though.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not used the mobile backend starter, I have used the Datastore extensively.

The datastore will automatically assign unique Keys to your entities when you store them.

I recommend the following piece of documentation about Keys: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#entity_keys

There you will see that the recommendation is to use the automatic, unique key and set your own value as a separate property.

If you do decide to set your own IDs on the actual Key, the official recommendation is to use a string, as numbers can collide with the auto generated IDs. The alternative is to reserve a range of numeric IDs to use.

But all this requires more custom code on your backend, and makes the interaction more complex.